# WCF service implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, wcf

I have WCF Service using .NET 4.0.

I have similar methods, similar code and I want use good patterns for improvement the code for get high level quality.
I want reuse code, maybe using `Action<T>`, and improve exception handling, ...

Is it possible?

**Interface**

```
[FaultContract(typeof(MyCompany.VSIntegration.SvcDespliegue.FaultContracts.DefaultFaultContract))]
    [OperationContract]
    QueryLogRes QueryLogsAdvanced(QueryLogReq req);

[FaultContract(typeof(MyCompany.VSIntegration.SvcDespliegue.FaultContracts.DefaultFaultContract))]
[OperationContract]
QueryLogRes QueryLogsByPeticionEV(QueryLogsByPeticionEVReq req);
```

**Implementation**

```
public QueryLogRes QueryLogsAdvanced(QueryLogReq req)
{
    try
    {
        IList<LogsDesplieguesDto> listLogs;
        bool result;

        ArgumentHelper.AssertNotNull<QueryLogReq>(req, "request");


        Log.Trace(LogCategoryNames.DebugGeneral, "QueryLogsAdvanced(" + req.ToString() + ")");

        using (var rpy = new LogsRepository())
        {
            listLogs = rpy.QueryLogs(req.Proyecto, req.Fecha, req.Servidor, req.Entorno, req.Usuario, req.Maquina, req.result, req.Etiqueta, req.PeticionEV);
        }

        result = (listLogs != null && listLogs.Count > 0);

        Trace.WriteLine("QueryLogsAdvanced Res: " + result);


        var res = new QueryLogRes(result, result ? "" : "No se han encontrado registros");
        if (!result) return res;

        Trace.WriteLine("QueryLogsAdvanced listLogs: " + listLogs.Count);

        foreach (var row in listLogs)
        {
            var dl = new DetailLog();
            dl.Entorno = row.Entorno;
            dl.Fecha = row.Fecha;
            dl.Log = row.Log;
            dl.Maquina = row.Maquina;
            dl.result = row.result;
            dl.Servidor = row.Servidor;
            dl.Usuario = row.Usuario;
            dl.Etiqueta = row.Etiqueta;
            dl.PeticionEV = row.PeticionEV;
            res.DetailsLogs.Add(dl);
        }

        Log.Trace(LogCategoryNames.DebugGeneral, "QueryLogsAdvanced. Logs encontrados: " + listLogs.Count);
        Trace.WriteLine("QueryLogsAdvanced. Logs encontrados: " + listLogs.Count);

        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log.Trace(LogCategoryNames.Errores, "EXCEPCION en 'QueryLogs': " + exc.Message);

        Exception auxExc = exc;
        bool rethrow = false;
        MyCompany.Frk.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionNotRethrowing(exc, NOMBRE_POLITICA_VSINTEGRATION, out auxExc, out rethrow);

        if (rethrow)
        {
            throw new FaultException<DefaultFaultContract>(new DefaultFaultContract(-1, auxExc.Message, Guid.Empty));
        }

        return new QueryLogRes(false, exc.Message);
    }
}


public QueryLogRes QueryLogsByPeticionEV(QueryLogsByPeticionEVReq req)
{
    try
    {
        IList<LogsDesplieguesDto> listLogs;
        bool result;

        ArgumentHelper.AssertNotNull<QueryLogsByPeticionEVReq>(req, "request");
        ArgumentHelper.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(req.PeticionEV, "PeticionEV");

        using (var rpy = new LogsRepository())
        {
            listLogs = rpy.QueryLogsByPeticionEV(req.PeticionEV);
        }

        result = (listLogs != null && listLogs.Count > 0);

        QueryLogRes res = new QueryLogRes(result, result ? "" : "No se han encontrado registros");
        if (result)
        {
            foreach (var row in listLogs)
            {
                DetailLog dl = new DetailLog();
                dl.Entorno = row.Entorno;
                dl.Fecha = row.Fecha;
                dl.Log = row.Log;
                dl.Maquina = row.Maquina;
                dl.result = row.result;
                dl.Servidor = row.Servidor;
                dl.Usuario = row.Usuario;
                dl.Etiqueta = row.Etiqueta;
                dl.PeticionEV = row.PeticionEV;

                res.DetailsLogs.Add(dl);
            }

        }

        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log.Trace(LogCategoryNames.Errores, "EXCEPCION en 'QueryLogs': " + exc.Message);

        Exception auxExc = exc;
        bool rethrow = false;
        MyCompany.Frk.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionNotRethrowing(exc, NOMBRE_POLITICA_VSINTEGRATION, out auxExc, out rethrow);

        if (rethrow)
        {
            throw new FaultException<DefaultFaultContract>(new DefaultFaultContract(-1, auxExc.Message, Guid.Empty));
        }

        return new QueryLogRes(false, exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Good**

- Wrapping `IDisposable`'s within a `using` statement
- Coding against an interface instead of an implementation
- Most parameters are named well

**Bad**

- Some parameters aren't named well
- Some usages of var, where the type isn't seen immediatetely
- unneccessary use of `IList.Count` instead of `Any()`
- Violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle

**Refactoring**

1. As the names `req`, `rpy`, `row`, `dl`, `res`, `result` aren't meaningful to **Mr.Maintainer**  we will just rename them.
   `req` -> `request`
   `res` -> `queryLogResult`
   `result` -> `hasLogEntries`
   `rpy`-> `logRepository`
   `row` -> `logEntry`
   `dl` -> `detailLog`
2. As the using of the var type at the `foreach` loop is to many rows away from the declaration of the `listLogs` variable, this is't as readable and understandable for **Mr.Maintainer** as it could be.
3. <s>As at declaration of an boolean variable the initial value is always `false` we can either skip the `= false` or add it for every boolean variable in the code.</s>
4. For cases we don't need to know the exact number of items in a `IList`, because we need to only know if there is **any** item in the list, we should use the `.Any()` method as this is faster.
5. The code after we have queried the repository is, setting aside some strings for logging, identical. This is screaming for extraction to separate method(s).

Let us start now with writing code. First we write a method which takes a `LogsDesplieguesDto` and returns a `DetailLog` object.

```
private DetailLog ToDetailLog(LogsDesplieguesDto logEntry)
{
    DetailLog detailLog = new DetailLog();

    detailLog.Entorno = logEntry.Entorno;
    detailLog.Fecha = logEntry.Fecha;
    detailLog.Log = logEntry.Log;
    detailLog.Maquina = logEntry.Maquina;
    detailLog.result = logEntry.result;
    detailLog.Servidor = logEntry.Servidor;
    detailLog.Usuario = logEntry.Usuario;
    detailLog.Etiqueta = logEntry.Etiqueta;
    detailLog.PeticionEV = logEntry.PeticionEV;

    return detailLog;
}
```

Now we add a new method which takes a `IList<LogsDesplieguesDto>` and returns a `IList<DetailLog>` object.

```
private IList<DetailLog> ToDetailLogList(IList<LogsDesplieguesDto> listLogs)
{
    IList<DetailLog> detailLogs = new List<DetailLog>();

    foreach (LogsDesplieguesDto logEntry in listLogs)
    {
        detailLogs.Add(ToDetailLog(logEntry));
    }
    return detailLogs;
}
```

Next we add a method to convert a `IList<LogsDesplieguesDto>` to a `QueryLogRes` object.

```
private const String noEntries = "No se han encontrado registros";
private QueryLogRes ToQueryLogResult(IList<LogsDesplieguesDto> listLogs)
{
    bool hasLogEntries = (listLogs != null && listLogs.Any());

    var queryLogResult = new QueryLogRes(hasLogEntries, hasLogEntries ? String.Empty : noEntries);

    if (!hasLogEntries) { return queryLogResult; }

    queryLogResult.DetailsLogs.AddRange(ToDetailLogList(listLogs));

    return queryLogResult;
}
```

Now the two methods of the original code will look like this

```
public QueryLogRes QueryLogsAdvanced(QueryLogReq request)
{
    try
    {
        ArgumentHelper.AssertNotNull<QueryLogReq>(request, "request");

        IList<LogsDesplieguesDto> listLogs;
        using (var logRepository = new LogsRepository())
        {
            listLogs = logRepository.QueryLogs(request.Proyecto, 
                request.Fecha, request.Servidor, 
                request.Entorno, request.Usuario, 
                request.Maquina, request.result, 
                request.Etiqueta, request.PeticionEV);
        }

        return ToQueryLogResult(listLogs);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Exception auxExc = exc;
        bool rethrow = false;
        MyCompany.Frk.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionNotRethrowing(exc, NOMBRE_POLITICA_VSINTEGRATION, out auxExc, out rethrow);

        if (rethrow)
        {
            throw new FaultException<DefaultFaultContract>(new DefaultFaultContract(-1, auxExc.Message, Guid.Empty));
        }

        return new QueryLogRes(false, exc.Message);
    }
}
```

---

```
public QueryLogRes QueryLogsByPeticionEV(QueryLogsByPeticionEVReq request)
{
    try
    {
        ArgumentHelper.AssertNotNull<QueryLogsByPeticionEVReq>(request, "request");
        ArgumentHelper.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(request.PeticionEV, "PeticionEV");

        IList<LogsDesplieguesDto> listLogs;
        using (var logRepository = new LogsRepository())
        {
            listLogs = logRepository.QueryLogsByPeticionEV(request.PeticionEV);
        }

        return ToQueryLogResult(listLogs);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Exception auxExc = exc;
        bool rethrow = false;
        MyCompany.Frk.Exceptions.ExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionNotRethrowing(exc, NOMBRE_POLITICA_VSINTEGRATION, out auxExc, out rethrow);

        if (rethrow)
        {
            throw new FaultException<DefaultFaultContract>(new DefaultFaultContract(-1, auxExc.Message, Guid.Empty));
        }

        return new QueryLogRes(false, exc.Message);
    }
}
```

For the exception handling, I don't know where the exception can occur.

**Additional thougths**
You can also convert the `ToQueryLogResult()`, `ToDetailLogList()` and `ToDetailLog()` methods to extension methods.
About the naming of classes not shown:
`LogsDesplieguesDto.result` seems like a property so it should be named using `PascalCase` like `LogsDesplieguesDto.Result`.The same is true for `DetailLog.result`and `QueryLogReq.result`.

As we see in the `ToDetailLog` method, `DetailLog` and also `LogsDesplieguesDto` are sharing a lot of properties which could be extracted to an interface. This interface could then be used as a parameter of the `DetailLog`'s constructor. In this way you could use the code of the `ToDetailLog` method in the `DetailLog`'s constructor.

Comment: "at declaration of an boolean variable the initial value is always `false`" No, it's not, it doesn't have any value. (For example `bool b; if (b) { }` won't compile.) You might be confusing local variables with fields, which do behave the way you describe.

Comment: @svick Thanks. Updated answer. I have mixed up with VB.NET.

Answer (score 3):

```
var dl = new DetailLog();
dl.Entorno = row.Entorno;
dl.Fecha = row.Fecha;
dl.Log = row.Log;
dl.Maquina = row.Maquina;
dl.result = row.result;
dl.Servidor = row.Servidor;
dl.Usuario = row.Usuario;
dl.Etiqueta = row.Etiqueta;
dl.PeticionEV = row.PeticionEV;
```

You can use object initializer syntax here:

```
var dl = new DetailLog
{
    Entorno = row.Entorno,
    Fecha = row.Fecha,
    Log = row.Log,
    Maquina = row.Maquina,
    result = row.result,
    Servidor = row.Servidor,
    Usuario = row.Usuario,
    Etiqueta = row.Etiqueta,
    PeticionEV = row.PeticionEV
};
```

If you do this kind of mapping often, you might want to consider using a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).